# Adding navigation properties to IdentityUser

Tags: abp

Using the ABP Suite, I am trying to add a navigation property to the IdentityUser class. In my case, I want to add a State entity as part of adding address properties to the IdentityUser. I have added several extended properties to the IdentityUser at this point, but I'm kind of scratching my head on this one.  I could go in and add the State by hand, but that would not generate the UI controls. Does anyone have a method for doing this?

Comment: Is anybody monitoring this tag anymore? I can't get support on the ABP.IO Commercial Support forum and nobody is responding here? Anybody else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add property by using [Object Extensions](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Object-Extensions) and set them as navigation properties by adding other entity Id as foreign key.

[Associate a department to a user from docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Module-Entity-Extensions#navigation-properties-foreign-keys):

```cs
ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.Modules()
    .ConfigureIdentity(identity =>
    {
        identity.ConfigureUser(user =>
        {
            user.AddOrUpdateProperty<Guid>(
                "DepartmentId",
                property =>
                {
                    property.UI.Lookup.Url = "/api/departments";
                    property.UI.Lookup.DisplayPropertyName = "name";
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

And the "/api/departments" endpoint:

```cs
[Route("api/departments")]
public class DepartmentController : AbpController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ListResultDto<DepartmentDto>> GetAsync()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```